# How can I parse a Cloudflare-guarded website with C#?

Tags: c#, parsing, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, cloudflare

I am trying to parse/scrape a Cloudflare-guarded website. When I use the browser and go to the page it does a few redirects and then returns the page. There is no that typical "Checking your browser before accessing...", just some redirects. Works fine in any browser.

When I try to scrape the page in C#, however, can't get the page using either `HttpWebRequest`, `WebClient` or `WebBrowser`.  The response is always forbidden. All the headers are set as in any browser.

So far I have only managed to get it to work with Selenium Chrome driver but, due to certain limitations, I would like to avoid it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

There's probably no way around a headless browser (like Selenium) to pass Cloudflare's checks.